# MAUI: the picker doesn't show items

Tags: c#, maui

I would like to use a Picker to allow select one element, but the picker doesn't show any intem.

I am using MAUI and .NET 7.

This is my view model:

```
    ObservableCollection<PrecisionesGpsUI> PrecisionesGps2;
    
private void InicializarPrecisionesGps()
    {
        PrecisionesGps2.Add("Alta");
        PrecisionesGps2.Add("Baja");
    }
```

This is the view:

```
<Picker HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PrecisionesGps2}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding PrecisionesGpsSelectedItem}"/>
```

But I don't see any item in the picker.

How could I show the items using the picker with MVVM?

Thanks.

EDIT: I add the class that I use for the items.

```
public partial class PrecisionGpsUI : ObservableObject
{
    private GeolocationAccuracy _precisionGps;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string _precision;


    public PrecisionGpsUI(GeolocationAccuracy paramPrecisionGps)
    {
        _precisionGps = paramPrecisionGps;
        this.Precision = paramPrecisionGps.ToString();
    }


    public GeolocationAccuracy GeolocationAccuracy()
    {
        return _precisionGps;
    }
}
```

Comment: ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"  , and instead Name - the thing you want to see. (If you show me your PrecisionesGpsUI, I can give you exact answer)

Comment: I have added the class for the items.

Comment: Just FYI your issue stems from the ItemSource you are assigning check my answer below

Comment: The ViewModel is incomplete and it's not clear whether the collection is set up correctly. It seems that the problem is the collection. Is it a property and does it get initialized correctly?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía so, what happens when you do ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Precision}"?

Comment: @ewerspej If this is the case, it would throw null pointer exceptions like crazy.

Comment: That's correct. It may also get overwritten with a new instance. We don't know if we can't see the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

`PrecisionesGps2` should be a property for it to reflect, fields don't work

```
public ObservableCollection<PrecisionesGpsUI> PrecisionesGps2 { get; set; }
```

If you are using `[ObservableProperty]` from the toolkit then you should know that it's based on certain assumptions as you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty)

> The name of the generated property will be created based on the field name. The generator assumes the field is named either lowerCamel, _lowerCamel or m_lowerCamel, and it will transform that to be UpperCamel to follow proper .NET naming conventions. The resulting property will always have public accessors, but the field can be declared with any visibility (private is recommended).

So in that case your field would look like below:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<PrecisionesGpsUI> precisionesGps2;
```

Comment: `precisionesGps2` should be an `ObservableCollection<PrecisionesGpsUI>` instead of `string?`.

Comment: Maybe also default-initialize it, because the call to `InicializarPrecisionesGps()` will throw when the collection isn't initialized. Then the Source Generator also isn't necessary, so the first part of your answer plus the initialization should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> ObservableCollection PrecisionesGps2;
> private void InicializarPrecisionesGps()
> {
> PrecisionesGps2.Add("Alta");
> PrecisionesGps2.Add("Baja");
> }

From the code you posted, I found several problems with your code when using it.

1.since you want to bind `PrecisionesGps2` to your picker, you need to add `{ get; set; }` to `PrecisionesGps2`.

```
   public  ObservableCollection<PrecisionesGpsUI> PrecisionesGps2 { get; set; }
```

And I also found that you initialized `PrecisionesGps2`  with string as follows:

```
     PrecisionesGps2.Add("Alta");
     PrecisionesGps2.Add("Baja");
```

So,why did you initialize it like this?

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> PrecisionesGps2 { get; set; }
```

And make sure initialize `PrecisionesGps2` and call method `InicializarPrecisionesGps();` in your MVVM.(e.g. call it on the constructor of your viewmodel).

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
   // public  ObservableCollection<PrecisionesGpsUI> PrecisionesGps2 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> PrecisionesGps2 { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel() {
        // init data
       //InicializarPrecisionesGps();
    }


    private void InicializarPrecisionesGps()
    {
        PrecisionesGps2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        PrecisionesGps2.Add("Alta");
        PrecisionesGps2.Add("Baja");
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui
             xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MVVMMauiApp.viewmodels"
             x:Class="MVVMMauiApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

        <Picker HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Title="Select an item"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PrecisionesGps2}"
                    />

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

2.from the edited part you shared,I found you defined item `PrecisionGpsUI`, but above code is `PrecisionesGpsUI`. These two are not a class at all, are you using it elsewhere or are you messing around while using these two classes?

Comment: Hi @Álvaro García, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.